# Rails push element to result query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can somebody give me advice. How can I push something to query results. For example:

```
@products = Product.where('active =?',true)
```

And now I want to push advertise box between every 9 .. 10 , 14 .. 15, 20 .. 21 result.

Comment: What is an advertise box? what is its type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do it in the view.

```
<%advertise_index = [9, 14, 20]%>
<%@products.each_with_index do |product, i|%>
   <%= product.name%> #whatever you want to show about the product
   <%if advertise_index.include?(i)%>
     #add advertise box
   <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: yes, exactly as it did I push extra box when index == X